# Cloning active partition to another drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, ssd

Can I clone my active partition (H:) in "Disco 1" to "Disco 0" and erase the old one without any risks of boot errors? What program should I use? Is Macrium Reflect all right?

I'd like to replace "Disco 1" with a 3TB HDD and since, AFAIK, MBR drives have to be under 2.2TB that'd look like a waste of space and money.

The transfer'd be from an HHD to a SSD.

My drives:
[image: My drives.]

Comment: you can clone it but might need to run recovery later from the Windows installation disk and run bootrec to fix booting issues. But cloning has nothing to do with replacing the disk. You can have a 16TB MBR disk with new 4KB-sector disks or 4TB MBR disk easily: [Make 3TB hard drive appear as two (2TiB+750GiB) with MBR](https://superuser.com/q/758262/241386). But it's still better to use GPT which has backup tables and checksums

Comment: `But it's still better to use GPT` : `bootrec` doesn't get you the right / other variant of Windows Boot Manager, nor would it create a ESP for you. One will need `bcdboot`. (Speaking of which, nothing would work if the machine doesn't have UEFI instead of BIOS.)

Comment: @TomYan that's wrong. [You can boot Windows from a GPT drive in BIOS mode using a software UEFI like DUET](https://superuser.com/a/1348314/241386), although obviously it'll be slower due to the need to boot into the software UEFI first. Anyway if a PC can run Windows 10, it highly likely has UEFI

Comment: No, YOU are wrong, as in you have a misconception on DUET or UEFI in general. When you are using DUET, you are technically on UEFI / booting in UEFI mode (and will be using the EFI variant of Windows Boot Manager). And my point was, the BIOS variant of Windows Boot Manager / the Windows MBR boot code does not support GPT.