# Can’t make partition on 500 GB SSD on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I want to make a new partition of 100 GB for installing Ubuntu on a 500 GB SSD, and I have about 150 GB free space in my `C:` partition (running Windows 10 OS), so I'm trying to shrink it.

But Windows Disk Manager says that I can shrink no more than 326 MB, which is too little to install another system.

Here's a screenshot from Windows Disk Manager:

[image: Screenshot from Windows Disk Manager]

It says that it can't shrink more
because `\pagefile.sys::$DATA` is unmovable:

[image: Event log ID 259 generated by Windows Disk Management app]

So I turned off paging on disk `C:`,
but still I can shrink no more than 326 MB from `C:`.

[image: Screen shot of paging settings]

UPDATE:
Defragmentation of disk was needed, it gave me about 32 GB place to shrink more.
Now I have porblem with anoother unmovable file 
\System Volume Information{...long_hex_value...}{...long_hex_value...}::$DATA

[image: More shrink place]

What could cause this? How can I move my unmovable file(s)?  How can I make a partition on my SSD for installation of another system?

UPDATE
Memomory problem solved. Just needed:

https://www.disk-partition.com/disk-management/unable-to-shrink-c-drive-0310.html

Disable System protection:Press “Win + R”< enter “SystemProperitiesProtecion.exe”< press “Enter”< click C drive< click “Configure”< select “Disable system protection”< click “Apply”< click “Yes”

Disable Hibernation:Click “Start”< type “CMD” in the Search box< right click “cmd”< choose “Run as administrator”< enter “powercfg.exe /hibernate off”

Disable Page files: Press “Win + R”< type “SystemPropertiesPerformance.exe”< Press “Enter”< click “Advanced” < click “Change under Virtual Memory”< uncheck “Automatically manage paging file size for all drives”< click C drive< set paging file size to No paging file< click “Set” < click “OK”< restart

Disable the kernel memory dump:Click “Start”< select “Control Panel”< click “System and Security”

Notice: You can restart computer after all the above set.

Unfortunately even though I got 133 GB free space to shrink, when I try to shrink even small disk amounts like 10 GB, disk manageres processes something for few minutes and then says, not enough space to shrink. Then if I check availble space to shrink it says i have 130 GB. Do not have ideas what to do now...

Comment: All the disk space is occupied by partitions. You need to shrink a partition first.

Comment: I have written few times that I am trying to shrink partition, and cant sshrink more space from C: than 326 MB

Comment: (1) Thanks for editing your question.  The information you have added absolutely should be added *as an edit* and ***not*** as a comment.  (2) Thank you for getting English versions of your screenshots.  (3) Did you try to defrag again after you disabled paging?  If not, please try that, and let us know what happens.

Comment: defragging the drive may help a little bit. But you should use a 3rd party partitioning tools like suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/1348415/241386). diskmgmt.msc is highly crippled in features compared to other external tools

Comment: Thanks, @G-Man defragmentation gave me 32 GB more, now I have porblem with new unmovable file, but maybe 32 will be enough for me

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you have 150 GB free ***within your C: partition*** doesn’t,
directly, help you to create a new partition. 
It is saying that you have 150 GB free in your C: filesystem. 
You can shrink the C: partition, e.g., to 375 GB,
which will create 100 GB *unallocated* space on the device. 
You can then create a new partition.

As todclifton says, this is like playing with matches and sharp knives. 
If you know what you’re doing, and you’re careful, they can be useful tools. 
If not, they can cause a lot of damage.

Comment: I would add that it isn't necessary to create a new partition from within Windows. Just shrink to get unallocated space, the Ubuntu installer will do the rest. Windows can't even natively create the file systems required by the main Linux partition therefore it would have to delete it anyway. And congratulations for the warning, this user clearly needs it.

Comment: Hi, added update in my question, because I cant write so many characters in comment. The problem is that shrinking does not work properly.

Answer (score -1):

Backup the drive, erase everything and partition it whatever way you want. If anything goes wrong restore the backup.